# Is there a gcc/clang flag to validate a C++ program without compiling

Tags: gcc, clang

Is there a gcc/clang flag to validate a C++ program without compiling it ?

In some of our per-commit-checks we only compile the program and pass if it compiles. We don't really need the compiled binary/executable. We want to save some time and compute power if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `-fsyntax-only` flag may be what you're looking for.  Though there could be some errors that would only be caught at later stages of compilation, so there isn't a 100% guarantee that code which passes `-fsyntax-only` would successfully compile.

Otherwise, it's worth noting that turning off optimization (`-O0`) by itself usually makes compilation many times faster.